# Declaring a variable array

Tags: linear-algebra, list-manipulation

I would like a declare a array `h = {h[1], h[2], ..., h[n]}` and I would like to keep `n` general for now. Then I would then like to define a function of this array:

```
W0[h_] := Sum[log[2*Cosh[h[i]], {1, n}]]
```

Typically, I would want to later differentiate with respect to say `h[1]` or something and then set all the `h[i]` to zero.

Comment: Look up `Indexed[]`.

Comment: You probably don't need a variable array (`List` in Mathematica) for this. As you see, the code for `W0` never references this list, it just uses `h[i]` directly. But you will need to get specific about `n` at some point. Mathematica has very limited support for lists of unspecified length.

Comment: Note that `log` should be `Log`. If you want to keep `n` general until the time of evaluation, you could instead define `W0[h_, n_Integer] := Sum[Log[2*Cosh[h[i]], {1, n}]]`.

Comment: You can make your function work for any length n: `W0[h_] := Sum[Log[2*Cosh[h[i]], {1, Length[h]}]]` or more simply: `W0[h_] := Total[Log[2*Cosh[h]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may do what you wish:

```
n = 5;
hVec = Array[h, 5];
w[hVec_] := Total[Log[2*Cosh[hVec]]];
```

Now w[hVec] gives:

```
Log[2 Cosh[h[1]]] + Log[2 Cosh[h[2]]] + Log[2 Cosh[h[3]]] 
    + Log[2 Cosh[h[4]]] + Log[2 Cosh[h[5]]]
```

For the requested derivative:

```
D[w[hVec], h[2]]
Tanh[h[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation on [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s)'s [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155277/11035),
which might be useful depending on your needs:

```
n=5;
h /: vec[h] := Array[h, n]

w[h_] := Total[Log[2*Cosh[vec@h]]]
```

Like bill s's approach, this will not deal with arbitrary `n`.