# Defining list of data

Tags: index

I need to define a list of parameters `A[i]` where `i` runs from 1 to some integer`N`. The expression for `A[i]` is given by some other indexed object `a[i]`. E.g.

```
`A[i] =  a[i]/(10 + a[i]^2)`
```

where `a[i]` are some free parameters and  I want to compute, say,

```
`Product[A[i]^2 + i^4,{i,1,N+2}]`
```

Comment: try `A[i_] =  a[i]/(10 + a[i]^2)` ?

Comment: if  *"`i` runs from `1` to some integer `N`"* but `Product[A[i]^2 + i^4,{i,1,N+2}]` you are going to have a problem; try something like `With[{n = 10},
 Array[(a[#] = RandomReal[]) &, n];
 A[i_] = a[i]/(10 + a[i]^2);
 Product[A[i]^2 + i^4, {i, 1, n}]
 ]`; also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155273/declaring-a-variable-array) might be relevant too.